# How to setup futures instruments in FinancialInstrument to lookup data from CSIdata

Tags: r, blotter, financialinstrument

**Background**

I am trying to setup my trade analysis environment. I am running some rule based strategies on futures on different brokers and trying to aggregate trades from different brokers in one place. I am using `blotter` package as my main tool for analysis.

Idea is to use `blotter` and `PerformanceAnalytics` for analysis of live performance of various strategies I am running.

**Problem at hand**

My source of future EOD data is CSIData. All the EOD OHLC prices for these futures are stored in CSV format in following directory structure. For each future there is seperate directory and each contract of the future has one csv file with OHLC price series.

```
|   
+---AD
|       AD_201203.TXT
|       AD_201206.TXT
|       AD_201209.TXT
|       AD_201212.TXT
|       AD_201303.TXT
|       AD_201306.TXT
|       AD_201309.TXT
|       AD_201312.TXT
|       AD_201403.TXT
|       AD_201406.TXT
|       AD_54.TXT
...      
+---BO2
|       BO2195012.TXT
|       BO2201201.TXT
|       BO2201203.TXT
|       BO2201205.TXT
|       BO2201207.TXT
|       BO2201208.TXT
|       BO2201209.TXT
|       BO2201210.TXT
|       BO2201212.TXT
|       BO2201301.TXT

...
```

I have managed to define root contracts for all the futures (e.g. in above case `AD`, `BO2` etc) I will be using in `FinancialInstrument` with CSIData symbols as primary identifiers.

I am now struggling on how to define all the actual individual future contracts (e.g. `AD_201203`, `AD_201206` etc)  and setup their lookup using `setSymbolLookup.FI`.

Any pointers on how to do that?

To setup individual future contracts, I looked into `?future_series` and `?build_series_symbols`, however, the suffixes they support seem to be only of Future Month code format. So I have a feeling I am left with setting up each individual future contract manually.  e.g.

```
build_series_symbols(data.frame(primary_id=c('ES','NQ'), month_cycle=c('H,M,U,Z'), yearlist = c(10,11)))
 [1] "ESH0" "ESM0" "ESU0" "ESZ0" "NQH0" "NQM0" "NQU0" "NQZ0" "ESH1" "ESM1" "ESU1" "ESZ1" "NQH1" "NQM1" "NQU1" "NQZ1"
```

I have no clue where to start digging for my second part of my question i.e. setting price lookup for these futures from CSI.

PS: If this is not right forum for this kind of question, I am happy to get it moved to right section or even ask on totally different forum altogether.

PPS: Can someone with higher reputation tag this question with `FinancialInstrument` and `CSIdata`? Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to get your data with an already existing `getSymbols` "method" without setting defaults (i.e. does it work without using `setSymbolLookup` or `setSymbolLookup.FI`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part just works.

```
R> currency("USD")
[1] "USD"
R> future("AD", "USD", 100000)
[1] "AD"
Warning message:
In future("AD", "USD", 1e+05) :
  underlying_id should only be NULL for cash-settled futures
R> future_series("AD_201206", expires="2012-06-18")
[1] "AD_201206"
R> getInstrument("AD_201206")
primary_id :"AD_201206"
currency   :"USD"
multiplier :1e+05
tick_size  : NULL
identifiers: list()
type       :"future_series" "future"
root_id    :"AD"
suffix_id  :"201206"
expires    :"2012-06-18"
```

Regarding the second part, I've never used `setSymbolLookup.FI`.  I'd either use `setSymbolLookup` directly, or set a `src` instrument attribute if I were going to go that route.

However, I'd probably make a `getSymbols` method, maybe `getSymbols.mycsv`, that knows how to find your data if you give it a `dir` argument.  Then, I'd just `setDefaults` on your `getSymbols` method (assuming that's how most of your data are stored).

I save data with `saveSymbols.days()`, and use `getSymbols.FI` daily.  I think it wouldn't be much effort to tweak `getSymbols.FI` to read csv files instead of RData files.  So, I suggest looking at that code.

Then, you can just

```
setDefaults("getSymbols", src="mycsv")
setDefaults("getSymbols.mycsv", dir="path/to/dir")
```

Or, if you prefer

```
setSymbolLookup(AD_201206=list(src="mycsv", dir="/path/to/dir"))
```

or (essentially the same thing)

```
instrument_attr("AD_201206", "src", list(src="mycsv", dir="/path/to/dir")
```

Comment: Thanks Garett, let me play around with your suggestions and report back my findings.

Comment: @geektrader, checkout the demo directory of FinancialInstrument as well as the examples in ?getSymbols.FI, ?saveSymbols.days, and ?instrument_attr

Comment: @geektrader, I misunderstood part of your question.  I actually don't use `build_series_symbols()` either.  Instead I use `twsInstrument::future_id`, but it doesn't support your YYYYMM format either so you'd have to create the symbols using `paste` (or `sprintf`) and `seq`

Comment: Thanks for following up. I am going the route of creating `getSymbols.mycsv` method. And regarding creating futures, I am just creating futures from filenames.